# Pythonic multidimensional matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

Matrix of floats A and B have dimensions `(1000,120)` and `(1000,120,3)`.

I want to multiply them so that the resulting matrix M should have dimensions (1000,120,3) and the logic should be that it `M[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0]` (with `A[0][0]` being scalar and `B[0][0]` an array with 3 values.

I can do it using loops, but looking for pythonic way of doing this. I have tried `A * B`, `np.dot(A, B)` and `A @ B`, but none of them generate the expected results (as I am probably missing a basic concept).

UPDATE:

```
A = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,120))
B = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,120,3))

A*B # ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,120) (1000,120,3)
np.shape(np.dot(A,B)) # (1000,1000,3)
np.shape(A@B) # (1000,1000,3)
np.tensordot(A,B,axes=1) # ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
A[..., None]*B # works, THANKS!
```

Comment: You can do `A[..., None]*B`; read up on _broadcasting_ which is the basic concept behind this.

Comment: It seems to be working - will look at broadcasting. Thanks! Edited the question for future reference

Comment: Re future reference, it is easier to see that this question is solved if there is an accepted answer. It is perfectly acceptable for you to answer your own question and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try tensordot

```
np.tensordot(A,B,axes=1)
```

If you give a small numerical example it will be easier to understand

Comment: See edits, although Paul answer, on the comments, worked well.

Comment: Yes, I thought what you want more like tensor-matrix product.

Answer (score 0):

@PaulPanzer came up with the right answer on the comments, which happens to be

```
A[..., None]*B
```